# Magento 2: Image resize is interrupted

Tags: magento2, error, product-images, image-resizing

I'm running the command **`bin/magento catalog:image:resize`** after updating to **Magento 2.3.2**, because all the images stopped working in frontend.

The process is interrupted after a while with this kind of error:

> File '/pub/media/catalog/product/v/u/file_name.jpg' does not exist.

Is there a way to bypass these kinds of errors somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Images stored in the database are transferred to the filesystem through file

```
/magentorootfolder/pub/get.php
```

So you will have to debug here. Also, make sure all permissions are set proper &
mod_rewrite is enabled (of apache/ngnix). To get the list of enabled modules in apache fire `php -m` command in terminal